# How do I return the id of a new post created in my sveltkit app using prisma?

Tags: fetch-api, prisma, sveltekit

I am trying to create a new post and have the server return the newly created post in the response. I only need the ID but I wouldn't mind returning the whole post and extracting the id. I have posted my server function and my client function below.

Her is my server function:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function POST({ request, response }) {
    const { author, comment, area_id, date, shift, ip } = await request.json();
    const createdPost = await prisma.TurnReport.create({
        data: {
            comment: comment,
            datetime: new Date().toISOString(),
            author: author,
            area_id: area_id,
            shift_date: date,
            shift_num: shift,
            ip: ip,
        }
    })
    return json(response)
}
```

Here is my client function:

```
const response = await fetch('/api/comment', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ author, comment, area_id, date, shift, ip }),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Message Sent successfully!');
                console.log(response)
            } else {
                console.log('Try agian...punk!');
            }
```

I am able to get a successful response and I can even console log the response but I do not see how to get the id out of it. I have read you can somehow return createdPost.id but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A response can contain *anything*, since this one returns JSON, you can use the convenience method `json()` to parse the response as such.

```js
const post = await response.json();
```

(Also, the API should probably return `createdPost`, not `response`.)

Comment: Thank you. I returned json(createdPost) on the server side like you said. And on the client side I was able to get the id by sonsole.log(JSON.stringify)(comment.id). I appreciate your help!